# How to apply transformation to svg path element?

Tags: javascript, svg

In my html file, I load an svg image and select one of its path elements. Now I want to rotate it, but I don't know how. The below code does not work.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Animate</title>
        <style>
        </style>
        <script src="../js/plugin/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <object data="images/steve/steve.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="steve" width="100%" height="100%"></object>

        <script>
            var steve = document.getElementById("steve");

            steve.addEventListener("load", function() {


                var svgDoc = steve.contentDocument; 
                var right_arm = svgDoc.getElementById("right_arm"); 



                //right_arm.rotate(90);    // THIS DOES NOT WORK


            },false);

        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform

You have to set a `transform` attribute directly on your SVG element. The `rotate` method takes a required argument which is the number of degrees you want to rotate your element.

```
right_arm.setAttribute('transform','rotate(45)');
```

You have to use the `.setAttribute(...)` method in javascript because if you were to do this in your HTML directly, you would literally specify attributes directly to the DOM element itself:

```
<rect transform="rotate(45)" ... />
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute

It's important to note that per the SVG specifications, you are only allowed certain attributes to your SVG elements. Take a look at all of the attributes applicable for the **rect** element, for example http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#RectElement.

Answer (score 0):

SVG elements do not share all of the CSS and JavaScript functionality that normal HTML elements do. There are some CSS properties that work differently on SVG elements, and some that don't work at all.

For this task, you can use the `transform` attribute on the `right_arm` element, and specify a rotation. The syntax is like this:

```
rotate(<a> [<x> <y>])
```

where `<a>` is the angle, and `<x> <y>` is an option (x,y) coordinate. In your example, if you want to rotate `right_arm` 90 degrees, you would do:

```
right_arm.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(90)");
```

`transform` does not work on all SVG elements, however. For more information on this, I would suggest looking at [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform).